# Some problems on making a automatic slide ImageButton

Tags: android, layout, slideshow, imagebutton

I have do some research on the web but I can't find the method for solving this problem. I want to make a button that will automatically slide from the current one to the new one (eg. ImageButton1 --> ImageButton2). I would like it to be slide from the left to the right.

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Please call you post your question clearly i m unable to get you

Comment: I want to make a button that can slide from one to another just like an slide show. The main idea just like the one on the http://apple.com .